# Created a git remote which points to an external git repo. Permission denied when I do a pull

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I have a project where I want to push "official" code to one server, while "test" code on another. I have two git repositories living in two completely different servers (for reasons that are not in my control). Let's call the servers Server_ONE and Server_TWO. Since the code for these two projects are the same, I want to manage this project from a single place on my local machine.

And so I did this:

```
#These work fine
git clone ssh://user@SERVER_TWO:my_project.git
git remote add Server1_branch user@SERVER_ONE:my_project.git

#This fails
git fetch Server1_branch master
user@SERVER_ONE's password: #I have no idea what password to enter. 
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

I know that Server_ONE is denying permissions. But I have no idea where to add permissions?

I am NOT using Github. These are both private repositories.

Comment: can you ssh user@SERVER_ONE ?i.e. does the permission issue only apply to git pushes and pulls?

Comment: Yea.. When I go a git clone ssh://user@SERVER_ONE:my_project.git, it works just fine.

Comment: Are you using gitolite? Have you checked permissions in $HOME/gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf?

Comment: Actually... I just discovered the solution! The problem was I had to do git remote add Server1_branch ssh://user@SERVER_ONE:my_project.git instead of git remote add Server1_branch user@SERVER_ONE:my_project.git

Answer (score 0):

Actually... I just discovered the solution! The problem was I had to do

```
git remote add Server1_branch ssh://user@SERVER_ONE:my_project.git
```

instead of

```
git remote add Server1_branch user@SERVER_ONE:my_project.git
```